# Maple unable to evalute function in whole range of plot

Tags: maple

Maple helpfully can work out the solution to Laplace's equation in a square region and give me the answer in closed form (in terms of an infinite sum).  If I try to plot the function of two variables as a 3d plot it gives me most of the surface but not all of it:

Here is the Maple code which produces the solution and turns it into an expression suitable for plotting

```
lapeq:=diff(v(x,y),x$2)+diff(v(x,y),y$2)=0;
bcs:=v(x,0)=0,v(0,y)=0,v(1,y)=0,v(x,1)=100;
sol1:=pdsolve({lapeq,bcs});
vxy:=eval(v(x,y),sol1);
```

the result of which is

[image: Maple representation of solution of Laplace equation]

All good so far.  Plotting it via

```
plot3d(vxy,x=0..1,y=0..1);
```

gives a result which is fine for x in the full range (0<x<1) but only for y between 0 and around 0.9:

[image: plot3d output from maple]

I have tried to evalf some point in the unknown region and Maple can't tell me numerical values there.  Is there any way to get Maple to "try a bit harder" to evaluate those numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting the number of terms in the sum

Compare

```
lapeq:=diff(v(x,y),x$2)+diff(v(x,y),y$2)=0;
bcs:=v(x,0)=0,v(0,y)=0,v(1,y)=0,v(x,1)=100;
sol1:=pdsolve({lapeq,bcs});
vxy:=subs(infinity=100,sol1);
plot3d(rhs(vxy),x=0..1,y=0..1);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With

```
restart;
lapeq:=diff(v(x,y),x$2)+diff(v(x,y),y$2)=0;
bcs:=v(x,0)=0,v(0,y)=0,v(1,y)=0,v(x,1)=100;
sol1:=pdsolve({lapeq,bcs});
vxy:=eval(v(x,y),sol1);
plot3d(vxy,x=0..1,y=0..1);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a huge fan of chopping the infinite sum at some value of the upper bound for `n`, without at least demonstrating either symbolically or numerically that it is justified. Ie, that chopping does not provide a false idea of convergence.

So, you asked how to make it work "harder". I'll take that to mean that you too might prefer to let `evalf/Sum` itself decide whether each infinite numeric sum converges -- rather than manually truncate it yourself at some finite value for the upper value of the range for `n`.

For fun, and caution, I also divide both numerator and denominator of `K` by the potentially large `exp` call (potentially much larger than 1). That may not be necessary here.

```
restart;
lapeq:=diff(v(x,y),x$2)+diff(v(x,y),y$2)=0:
bcs:=v(x,0)=0,v(0,y)=0,v(1,y)=0,v(x,1)=100:
sol1:=pdsolve({lapeq,bcs}):
vxy:=eval(v(x,y),sol1):

K:=op(1,vxy):
J:=simplify(combine(numer(K)/exp(2*Pi*n)))
   /simplify(combine(denom(K)/exp(2*Pi*n))):

F:=subs(__d=J,
    proc(x,y) local k, m, n, r;
      if y<0.8 then
        r:=Sum(__d,n=1..infinity);
      else
        UseHardwareFloats:=false;
        m := ceil(1*abs(y/0.80)^16);
        r:=add(Sum(eval(__d,n=m*n-k),n=1..infinity),
               k=0..m-1);
      end if;
      evalf(r);
    end proc):

plot3d( F, 0..1, 0..0.99 );
```

[image]

Naturally this is slower than mere chopping of terms to obtain a finite sum. And you might be satisfied with some technique that establishes that the excluded terms' sums are negligible.